# Globally define Lomboks @ExtensionMethod

Tags: java, extension-methods, lombok

Is it possible to set the @ExtensionMethod for the whole project?
For example if I extend Object with a method isNull(), would it be possible to use that in the whole project with only define the @ExtensionMethod in for example a config class and use it everywhere without declaring it on each class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lombok contributor here:

No. The primary reason is 'surprises' - lombok would then be having an effect on a source file that has zero mentions of lombok, anywhere in side it (no types or imports; a CMD+F for `lombok` would produce zero results), and yet, doesn't compile without it.

Lombok does have a config system ([`lombok.config`](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration)) and that would be the place to define some fully qualified class names to be treated as automatically considered sources of extension methods for all java source files in the directory where this config file appears and all subdirs of that directory. But, this feature doesn't exist right now, and won't, until I and other major contributors hold a bit of a debate on whether we want to open this can of worms.

Some meet-in-the-middle solution where there *is* a list of 'default extensions', but you still need to enable it by annotating the class with `@DefaultExtensionMethods` or what not (or just `@ExtensionMethod` and nothing more, with no arguments) might be where we draw the line. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: After thinking about it, it's no different than the Getter annotation for example. With the Getter annotation, the class with the definition is manipulated, not the calling class.  There the calling class also knows nothing about Lombok annotations. According to the logic the ExtensionMethod annotation should also work like Getter. ExtensionMethod is set to the class that extends the method and the callers can use the function without any additional annotation.